# Which one is a good collocation? "handmade merchandise" or "handmade goods"?

Tags: word-choice, collocations

Which one is natural? I am talking about those kind of handmade products which visitors usually buy as souvenirs.

> 1. Tourists buy **handmade goods** from local craft
>    fairs.
> 2. Tourists buy **handmade merchandise** from local craft
>    fairs.

Comment: As soon as the goods are for sale they become merchandise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least to me (non-native speaker), *handmade goods* sounds more natural. Maybe *handcrafted merchandise* would be more suitable with the *merchandise* word.

Answer (score 1):

As a native BE speaker, I would say that the 2 sentences are interchangeable. Both sound natural to me. There is nothing to chose between them. Except that I would say "...**at** local craft fairs" since the fair is a place not a person. I would buy goods **from** the market traders.

One word that has come into fashion, particularly for items of food, is **artisanal** which means made by traditional, non mechanical methods. For example

> Tourists buy **artisanal bread and cheese** at local markets.